# Files not showing in browser, but it is in explorer

Tags: php, browser, sublimetext2, wamp

I'm looking for header.php.

When I navigate to the folder via a browser (ff and chrome), it's not there:
[image: header.php is not in the folder acording to the browser]

But it's there in Windows Explorer:

[image: but it is there in windows explorer]

I'm using Sublime Text 2 and my folder structure is on WAMP.

Originally I had this file in a different directory, and there was some confusion about which one I was editing, but I deleted the other file, and made sure I was editing the correct one.

I've tried clearing the cache, but even when I went there in chrome, which had not navigated to that folder before, it still didn't see it.

**Update**: I deleted the file in explorer, then saved it back, along with footer.php. Footer shows up but header still does not.

Comment: Are you using an .htaccess `IndexIgnore` directive at all in `/life2`

Comment: Not that I know of, how do I check that?