# Directory hidden on web browsers but visible on windows explorer

Tags: php, laravel, apache, webserver, wamp

I'm having an issue similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21358358/files-not-showing-in-browser-but-it-is-in-explorer#)

I cloned a laravel project from Github, after setting up the project on my local server (wamp) with a hostname for it, I typed the hostname on my browser (chrome) and got "500 internal server error". I had never gotten this issue before because setting up a virtual host on wamp is easy, I do it all the time.

Then I decided to view the project root directory from my browser and noticed that all the directories and files inside it were listed except the public directory.

The public directory is visible from my editor and windows explorer but is hidden when I try to view it from my Web browser thus making it impossible for me to view/run the app

How do I make visible the public directory on my browser?

Whenever I empty the .htaccess file in that public directory, it becomes visible on the browser but when I add the default laravel content of the htaccess file it becomes hidden again.

Please what could be the cause??

I tried setting the permission of that public directory to 777 using php `chmod` method but directory is still hidden from browser.

Comment: Most likely a wrong `DocumentRoot` for your vhost. It should be the `public` folder, not the root of your project

Comment: @brombeer the DocumentRoot has the path to the public folder, I'm sure. I use the same settings for other projects and they are all working as expected. Only this one

Comment: Does the project also not work when using `php artisan serve` instead of WAMP?

Comment: "_Then I decided to view the project root directory from my browser_" How did you do that?

Comment: @brombeer i viewed the project root by typing `localhost/myProjectFolder` in the address bar of the browser, it listed all the folders and files inside the project folder except the public folder

Comment: So, does the project work using `php artisan serve`?

Comment: @brombeer yes it works with `php artisan serve`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally saw the culprit.

saw this line `SecFilterEngine Off` in my htaccess file and when i commented it out, the public folder magically appeared. i really don't know why, maybe it had something to do with `mod_security` which was disabled.